# NOAA API - climate normals dataset and stationID issues

Tags: api, weather, noaa

I’m attempting to create a mobile app feature for farmers/gardeners where the first and last frost date is returned from NOAA data based on zip code ( or lat and long). There are a number online, but here’s a nice example: https://davesgarden.com/guides/freeze-frost-dates/index.php?q=78701&submit=Go.

And another here: https://www.almanac.com/gardening/frostdates/zipcode/78701.

Given a stationID, I can successfully query the API for the US Climate Normals (dataset: NORMAL_ANN) from 1981-2010.

The NOAA datasets and documentation seems very fragmented and I’m a bit stuck.

I have two questions.

1. There is a newer dataset (https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/products/land-based-station/us-climate-normals) I would like to use, but I can’t seem to access that by an API? I can’t really bulk download the data and distribute it with the app as that would be too big. Is there’s an alternative way to access that per station that I’m missing?
2. What’s the best way to lookup the stations for the data I need? Currently, I convert the user’s zip to a FIPS (county) code and request a list of stations via the 2.0 API. Then I can request my specific data types (90% chance of last 32 degree temp for instance) from one of the stations returned. However, the stations I get back from this approach are different than the stations in the examples I provided above. The first station listed on the web example is “Austin Mueller Airport” which isn’t even returned for the FIPS code in Travis County… so clearly there is another method being used.

Thanks for any help or insight you can provide.